# Should verb "is/are" stay before or after a pronoun in the end of the question?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, questions, pronouns

Such sentence for instance: `Who knows what creatures are these?`.
Text editors correct this as `Who knows what creatures these are?`.
Which is right or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is more normal.

*These* is the subject (not *what creatures* - that is the complement).

In a direct question we invert the subject and verb (or auxiliary - irrelevant here):

> What creatures **are these**?

In an indirect (or embedded) question, we do not invert, so the subject precedes the verb:

> Who knows what creatures **these are**?